# Объединить табличные части xml по заголовкам в xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть XML файл

```
    <results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <classData>
        <PromoCode>20230520</PromoCode>
        <Type_Promo>Прочее</Type_Promo>
        <Инициатор>Иванов И. И.</Инициатор>
        <StartDate>2023-07-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2023-07-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
        <Цены>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006699</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>58.00</Price>
          </row>
        </Цены>
        <Ограничения>
          <row>
            <PlanSum>7000.000000000000</PlanSum>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
          </row>
        </Ограничения>
      </classData>
      <classData>
        <PromoCode>20230520</PromoCode>
        <Type_Promo>Прочее</Type_Promo>
        <Инициатор>Иванов И. И.</Инициатор>
        <StartDate>2023-07-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2023-07-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
        <Цены>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006665</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>57.00</Price>
          </row>
        </Цены>
        <Ограничения>
          <row>
            <PlanSum>7000.000000000000</PlanSum>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
          </row>
        </Ограничения>
      </classData>
     
      <classData>
      </classData>
    </results>
```

Требуется преобразовать в

```
    <results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <classData>    
        <PromoCode>20230520</PromoCode>
        <Type_Promo>Прочее</Type_Promo>
        <Инициатор>Иванов И. И.</Инициатор>
        <StartDate>2023-07-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2023-07-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
        <Цены>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006699</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>58</Price>
          </row>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006665</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>57</Price>
          </row>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0024601</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006699</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>67</Price>
          </row>
          <row>
            <OriginProductId>PR0024601</OriginProductId>
            <OriginCustomerId>ТКТ0006665</OriginCustomerId>
            <Price>68</Price>
          </row>
        </Цены>
        <Ограничения>
          <row>
            <PlanSum>7000</PlanSum>
            <OriginProductId>PR0018423</OriginProductId>
          </row>
          <row>
            <PlanSum>PR0024601</PlanSum>
            <OriginProductId>5000</OriginProductId>
          </row>
        </Ограничения>
      </classData>
      </results>
```

Кто может помочь?